# Why is my form_tag making a POST request instead of a PUT request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form to change a password and upon submit the form should make a put request.

```
<%= form_tag authors_change_password_path, method: :put  do %>
  <%= fields_for :author do |f| %>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="card-title">
              Change password  </div>
        </div>

          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :current_password %>
                <%= f.password_field :current_password, class: 'form-control' %>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :new_password %>
                <%= f.password_field :new_password, class: 'form-control' %>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :new_password_confirmation %>
                <%= f.password_field :new_password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
          <%= f.submit "Change password", class: 'btn btn-warning' %></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div
      <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

when I click on submit i get the following error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/authors/change_password"
```

I can not figure out why it is making a POST request because i state in the options hash "method: :put" in the line

```
<%= form_tag authors_change_password_path, method: :put  do %>
```

I have tried variations on this line as follows:

```
<%= form_tag (authors_change_password_path, method: :put)  do %>
<%= form_tag authors_change_password_path, {method: :put}  do %>
<%= form_tag (authors_change_password_path, {method: :put})  do %>
<%= form_tag authors_change_password_path, method: "put"  do %>
```

my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :authors
  root to: 'blog/posts#index'

  namespace :authors do
    get '/account' => 'accounts#edit', as: :account
    put '/info' => 'accounts#update_info', as: :info
    put '/change_password' => 'accounts#change_password', as: :change_password
    resources :posts do
      put 'publish' => 'posts#publish', on: :member
      put 'unpublish' => 'posts#unpublish', on: :member
    end
  end

  scope module: 'blog' do
    get 'about' => 'pages#about', as: :about
    get 'contact' => 'pages#contact', as: :contact
    get 'posts' => 'posts#index', as: :posts
    get 'posts/:id' => 'posts#show', as: :post
  end
```

Where am i going wrong? it is strange since i am following a tutorial and i have the same code as the tutorial but i get the error and the tutorial works fine. 
 here is the code. https://github.com/StephenFiser/FrogBlog/blob/master/config/routes.rb
and the video link for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JP31T66tU7w

EDIT: PUT request is just another form of POST. But actually its making a PUT call. Just inspect the HTML form generated. You will find a hidden field in the form which Rails maintain for making PUT calls.
Don't worry you are actually making a PUT call behind the scenes.

above edit is not by me the author in case of confusion.

EDIT 2: html output for the form

```
<form action="/authors/change_password" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="pU1oE+BAJjNF+bfSaGqaY27ECYoNfu8K6u71WLUNjV316po8HykOqib0ghhYTd9jD7nV8z+JrMvXO9VSujMXiA==">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="card-title">
              Change password  </div>
        </div>

          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <div class="field">
                <label for="author_current_password">Current password</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="author[current_password]" id="author_current_password">
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item">
              <div class="field">
                <label for="author_new_password">New password</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="author[new_password]" id="author_new_password">
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item">
              <div class="field">
                <label for="author_new_password_confirmation">New password confirmation</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="author[new_password_confirmation]" id="author_new_password_confirmation">
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
          <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Change password" class="btn btn-warning" data-disable-with="Change password"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div></form>
```

Comment: Could you inspect the `form` and show me the generated HTML?

Comment: i am not sure the purpose of the edit to my post above. what action should i take?

Comment: @fongfan999 see Edit 2  for html output

Comment: It looks weird :(. Please show me the output of this command: rake routes | grep change_password

Comment: @fongfan999 output of "rake routes | grep change_password –" is: authors_change_password PUT    /authors/change_password(.:format)     authors/accounts#change_password

Comment: Dont create the form manually, that way to code is very bad, the first form is making a post request because it doesn't know that is updating something, if the author you are updating is the `current_author`, use the `current_author` helper on the route like `authors_change_password_path(current_author)` (you should change the route too) by the way, also your controller is accounts_controller. Too messy code to help you.